# Declaring syntax error int main()

Tags: c++, function, syntax-error

So I am new to programming and i am trying to make a program that removes white space from a word that is put in. unfortnately, when I add a void function, it gives me a declartion error.

```
include<iostream.h>
include<string.h>

void removeSpaces(char secretWord[30], int n)
int main()
{
    char secretWord[30];
    int n;

    cout << "Enter a secret word: " << endl;
    cin >> secretWord;

    cout << secretWord <<endl;

    removeSpaces(secretWord[30], n)
    cout << n << endl;
    return 0;
}

void removeSpaces(char secretWord[30], int& n)

{

    int n;
    bool found;

    n = 0;

    while (secretWord[30] && n >= 0)
        {
            if(secretWord[30] != ' ')
                found = true;

            else
                n=n-1;
        }
}
```

the error is on the int main() line. any help would be great. thanks!

Comment: you need a semicolon after declaring `removeSpaces`

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the previous line.

Comment: stop using ".h" header
use #include<iostream> & <#include<cstring>

Comment: You seriously need a good training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before:

```
void removeSpaces(char secretWord[30], int n)
```

After:

```
void removeSpaces(char secretWord[30], int n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors in your code :-

1. Prototype of removeSpaces : `void removeSpaces(char secretWord[30], int &n);`
2. Calling of function : `removeSpaces(secretWord, n);`
3. Clash of function argument `n` & local variable `n`
4. Passing `n` as reference when not initialized.
5. Numerous logical errors : There are so many including the function itself, I mean does it actually remove spaces, what does `n` do, why is `found` present, etc, etc.